# Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install failing to autoload

Tags: configuration, patches, fatal-error, autoloader

I patched our site with SUPEE 6482 and, once clearing the cache, I get the same issue described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68010/error-after-successfull-patch-supee-5994-class-mage-install-controller-router) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366629/error-including-mage-install-controller-router-install-php-in-magento):

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install' not found in /var/www/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 138

We did not get this error after SUPEE 5994 as others did.

It is not due to compilation (that has been disabled and cleared), cache (both main cache and sessions have been emptied several times, PHP opcache is disabled), nor the server itself (have restarted Apache and the entire box). The file definitely exists (others report patching failed to create it) and has the right owner and permissions.

I'm guessing that the file isn't able to be autoloaded but I don't know why.

I tried commenting out the router conf (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30384711/315024)) and manually clearing the cache again. This does prevent the fatal error, as Magento no longer tries to load the file, but that isn't a solution because that code needs to be there to patch a hole.

Answer (score 0):

The interessting question is:

> Why is magento searching for `Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install` in /var/www/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php

This is an install router, so this should only happen, when magento tries to show the installer.

And magento autoloader should find the file, therefore I assume the autoloader is either not initialized yet or somehow broken.

So when you want to debug THIS problem, I would start by checking whether the autoloader is called to find this class.

But I think the more important problem to solve is:

> Why is magento trying to use an Install router?