# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install' not found

Tags: security, server, command-line

in site 1 , we did't installed security patches, but in site 2 we installed security patches.

after copying the folder,

i am getting the error as follows :

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install' not found in /var/www/html/1/10/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 138

i saw this link : [Error after successfull patch SUPEE-5994: Class 'Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install' not found](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68010/error-after-successfull-patch-supee-5994-class-mage-install-controller-router)

but i am new to ssh.

please give me some idea about that link or what need to be done to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you disabled the compiler and cleared the cache ??

Comment: no i i wll try now..... how to disable complier using ssh commands....

Comment: post your comment as answer.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the compiler and cleared the cache
run this command in ssh:

```
$ php shell/compiler.php disable
```

For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538154/magento-died-after-compilation-how-to-disable-using-compiled-files-without-admi)