# Magento 1.9.0.1 Error on Multiple Stores after Supee 8788

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-8788

I have a few Magento shops which gets this error after installing the Supee 8788 Patch. I cannot find anyone who have the same problem on Google...

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Uploader_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /www/app/Mage.php on line 547

**Questions**
What could be causing this? 
Isn't there a way to see the stacktrace to see where it's called from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it's caused by the fact that the patch was not installed properly.

The patch adds a new file `app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php` which matches the `Mage_Uploader_Helper_Data` class.

First, ensure that file is present.

If it's not present, that means the patch did not work.

If it's present, I suggest you flush the cache and recompile (if you have compilation enabled)

Comment: It was the compilation that caused the error. Thanks!!

Comment: In my case, compilation was disabled prior to installing the patch and afterwards I couldn't get into the admin panel at all. Recompiling via the CLI as described in this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68010/error-after-successfull-patch-supee-5994-class-mage-install-controller-router solved the problem for me.